# Git pull, and merged

Tags: git

I've pushed my local changes from branch, and than checkout to master and done pull. Are my local changes now on master, and would it be visible to ohers when they switch to master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you committed your changed to master, and pushed master, then yes.  If you committed your changes to an arbitrary branch and pushed *that* branch, then no.
2. Unless your repository has any kind of access control, then they'll be visible to everyone.  By default, Git has no such notion of access control, so if you're running Git on some server you had spun up, it'll be open for anyone with access to that server to see.

   Discussions on how to set up security are *well* outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I commited my changes to arbitray branch. So my changes aren't yet on master? But when I ckeckout on master, in source tree it shows "Merge remote-tracking branch <my_branch_name>". So can anyone explain me what happens? I'm new at Git.

Comment: @user3568043:  From this perspective I've answered your questions; it would behoove you to peruse [the official book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to gain a clearer understanding of Git in general.